# javascript getInterval call with var name

Tags: javascript, justgage

can you advice in the following general javascript implemetation issue  :
i build the jastgage object dynamicly from JStree , i get an array and for each elemenet in the array i bulid 3 diff jastgage objects
each object have uniuck name .

```
$('<div id="g1_'+i+'" class="gaugeObj"></div>').appendTo(".inner");
window["g1_"+i] = new JustGage({
    id: "g1_"+i,
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    gaugeWidthScale:"0.55",
    title:"CPU:"+ arrSel[i]                                         
});
```

"i" is the index number in the array ... ( my obj name are j1_0 , j2_0 , j3_0 , ... j1_1 , j2_1 , j3_1 ..... )
I can see all object as needed, but when I try to refresh the values (just after I create the object ) with

```
setInterval(function() {
    g1_(i).refresh(getRandomInt(0, 42));                     
 }, 1500);
```

it fails , nothing is refreshed, the debug  shows
    : g1_ is not defined

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not seeing anywhere you are defining a function named g1_.  Where are you expecting it to come from?

Comment: You need to write:

setInterval(function() {
                    g1_1.refresh(getRandomInt(0, 42));                     
                       }, 1500);

Comment: @Aravind these id's are dynamic, `i` is required.

Comment: i define the ovject with "window["g1_"+i] = new JustGage({" ...

Answer (score 1):

You stored the `g1_` set in your window object, so just access them the same way you defined them.

```
window["g1_"+i].refresh(getRandomInt(0, 42));
```

As it stands, JavaScript is looking for a function called `g1_` and that's not a function, it's undefined. You'd see that in your console

Comment: TypeError: window[("g1_" + i)] is undefined

Comment: Log the window object and see what is defined